# How to expand a data scale on NVD3 line chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Now I've got extra ends like this.

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of those ends? Currently I'm using this setup:

```
  nv.addGraph ->
    chart = nv.models.lineChart()
      .showLegend(false)
      .width(elem.width())
      .margin(top: 10, left: 50, bottom: 20, right: 50)

    chart.xAxis
      .tickValues(_.map(data[0].values, (d) -> d.x))
      .tickFormat((d) -> d3.time.format('%d/%m')(new Date(d)))
      .tickPadding(10)

    chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format('+.2f'))
      .tickPadding(10)
      .showMaxMin(false)

    d3.select(elem[0])
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(0)
      .call(chart)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to expand domain for y axis using `yDomain` chart option:

```
chart.yDomain([-0.70, 0.50]);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! But I can't find any of this `yDomain` documentation, any reference?

Comment: Actually I'm based on the [source](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js) code and d3.js [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference). But I also use [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) directive, that parses nvd3 core api completely. You can find and customize most available options on the [live edit](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart) page in `extended` mode.

Comment: @krispo so how would you do that in angular-nvd3? I am unable to re scale y axis...thanks

Comment: I was looking for a list of options for nv3d also.  Did find one finally at https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html